# How to disable FLAG_SECURE by modifying an APK file?

Tags: applications, security, screenshots

I want to mod an APK so that its `FLAG_SECURE` can be disabled. Can anyone please guide me in doing that?

I have used `apktool` to decompile the app, but I don't know which specific file to find in smali to disable this.

Answer (score 3):

There is not one specific file you have to edit. Instead, you have to search all smali files for a specific call. Luckily, the smali syntax is very specific so that you can search easily using a full-text search tool. I prefer Agent Ransack (Windows) or  `grep -R` (on the command line).

In detail, you have to search the smali files for one of the following calls:

```
Landroid/view/Window;->setFlags(II)V
Landroid/view/Window;->addFlags(I)V
```

Before each call in the same line, there is noted which registers contain the parameters.

#### addFlags

```
const/16 v2, 0x2000
invoke-virtual {v1, v2}, Landroid/view/Window;->addFlags(I)V
```

The second entry in the curly brackets is the interesting one (`v2` in the example).

If this parameter is set to `0x2000`. In detail, this is a bitmask and if the 14th bit is set, the screenshot protection is applied to the current screen.

Effectively, only the fourth position matters. If it is `2` or `6` (2+4) or `A` (8+2) or `C`(2+4+8) then the bit you are searching is set. But usually (in 99% of all cases), you will find the value `0x2000`.

Search the lines before the `invoke-virtual` if there is a command that sets the register we are looking for such as: `const/16 v2, 0x2000`.

If there is the call, and the second parameter has a parameter with the hexadecimal `2` at the mentioned position, you can simply comment out the whole `invoke-virtual ...` line by placing a `#` in front of the line.

#### setFlags

```
const/16 v1, 0x2000
const/16 v2, 0x2000

invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v2}, Landroid/view/Window;->setFlags(II)V
```

For `setFlags`, it is very similar, just that the `0x2000` parameter has to be present in the second `v1` and the third `v2` mentioned register in the curly brackets.

Do that with every occurrence of `setFlags`/`addFlags` invocations.

Again, comment out the whole `invoke-virtual ...` line by placing a `#` in front of the line.

#### Rebuild APK

Then rebuild (`apktool b ...`) the APK file (you can find it in the `dist` subfolder) and then use `apksigner` sign the built APK with a custom certificate and you are ready to install the app. `apksigner` is part of Android SDK, but can also be downloaded manually, see e.g. [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74171036/150978).

Alternatively for signing you can use a tool like [uber-apk-signer](https://github.com/patrickfav/uber-apk-signer/releases) which simplifies APK certificate and key generation + signing the APK.